# Can't reference a variable from App.config

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, app-config

I'm trying to reference a variable from App.config in my C# file. Here's a sample of my code.

**App.config:**

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ErrorEmails" value="fakeCompany@fakeCompany.com"/>
</appSettings>
```

**Code:**

```
SettingsIO setIO = new SettingsIO();
public static string To = setIO.ReadSetting("ErrorEmails");
```

The error reads:

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or preperty 'test.setIO'.

Should I be using a `GET` function? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `Should I be using a GET function?`  Sounds like you've already answered your own question.

Comment: You don't show any context, but `setIO` appears to be a instance member and `To` is a `static` member. You can't reference `setIO` in a `static` method or member (i.e. exactly what the error message says) because you don't have an instance of the object.

Comment: `public static string To = new SettingsIO().ReadSetting("ErrorEmails");`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `system.configuration` class.

```
string str = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager
                                 .AppSettings["someAppSetting"]
                                 .ToString();
```

Comment: It looks like `SettingsIO` is his own class that is wrapping this behavior.

Answer (score 1):

From the error text I would guess that the lines you show are some class members declaration, i.e. code looks like this:

```
class MyAwesomeClass
{
    SettingsIO setIO = new SettingsIO();
    public static string To = setIO.ReadSetting("ErrorEmails");
}
```

Please notice, that `To` is a static member, while `setIO` is not.

The error message pretty clearly tells you that you cannot reference non-static member for member initialization. Static members are created at program start-up time, while non-static ones are only created when you create instance of your class, so there is no way to access non-static members when there is no instance of your class exists.

In order to make it work, you have to make both members static (It won't work if you make both non-static, but you can initialize them in class constructor instead in that case):

```
class MyAwesomeClass
{
    static SettingsIO setIO = new SettingsIO();
    public static string To = setIO.ReadSetting("ErrorEmails");
}
```

or

```
class MyAwesomeClass
{
    SettingsIO setIO;
    public string To {get; private set; } // don't make members public, use auto-properties instead

    public MyAwesomeClass
    {
        setIO = new SettingsIO();
        To = setIO.ReadSetting("ErrorEmails");
    }
}
```